# How to process commandline arguments in neutralinojs

Tags: neutralinojs

There is some content that is served from one program that opens up neutralino app using commands. I would like to pass my custom command line arguments to the neutralino app whenever it is run for example;

```
neu run -- --serv=127.0.0.1:8000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neutralinojs provides command-line arguments via the `NL_ARGS` global variable. You can see all supported global variables from the [documentation](https://neutralino.js.org/docs/api/global-variables#predefined-global-variables).

To obtain the command-line argument you need to find it from the `NL_ARGS` array that contains all command-line arguments. Neutralinojs doesn't provide a built-in parser for command-line arguments. Therefore, you need to split and get the value from `--serv=value`.